# JSON File I/O : Extra Data Error

Tags: python, json, file, io

I am learning Python currently. For a small project, I am writing a script to dump and load JSON extracted from the web. The file needs to be constantly updated after pulling the data each time and for the same, I have written the following code.

```
    with open(os.path.join(d,fname),'a+') as f:
        try:
            f.seek(0)
            t = json.load(f)
            for i in t:
                tmp[i]=t[i]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e,"New File ",fname," is created in ",d)
        f.truncate()
        json.dump(tmp,f)
```

I have put a try-catch block since the first time this program runs, the file would have no data written.

When I run the script, it works as expected but when I run the same script the fourth time, it gives EXTRA DATA exception.

Extra data: line 1 column 29245 (char 29244) New File  TSLA_dann  is created in  2017-12-20

I am not sure how another dictionary is being written in the file. Please guide me to the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nearly impossible to write another json with such code. Your code is not good. You mix too much try open, seek and truncate, wrong file mode choice maybe. I will teach you little to be much better:

1. try should cover only what can raise error.
2. Seek is not need always seek(0) is after open.
3. open(x, 'a+) mean append to the end I think (i can be reason of error).
4. use spaces.
5. be patient.

Problem is probably 'a+' mode but it is not matter clean the code :)

Believe me I writing 250 000 line programs without problems.

Clean code for you as good example should work (I was not tested - you can fix it if one letter missed or just run):

```
# read
file_path = os.path.join(d, fname)
with open(file_path, 'r') as f: # 'r' is read can be skipped
    try:
        t = json.load(f)
    except Exception as e:
        print('%s %s' % (e, file_path))

for i in t:
    tmp[i] = t[i]

# write
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(tmp, f)
```